# NodeJs/electron: Convert one timezone to the other in website /client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, timezone, electron, momentjs

I am receiving one string from API as mentioned below:

```
var time = 2018-01-31T11:11:41+05:30;
```

Now the next step is I have to convert this time to browser(client side) local-time zone.

I am using moment Js but unable to find the proper function to achieve this conversion.

Comment: You can do something like this, without moment Js also,:
`var time = new Date("2018-01-31T11:11:41+05:30"); 
 console.log(time.toLocaleDateString())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/).

Since your string includes utc offset moment takes it in account, but it creates and object in local mode because:

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.

Here a live sample:

```js
var time = '2018-01-31T11:11:41+05:30';
console.log( moment(time).format() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I got it. You save my day ! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you may want date to be shown like this?  `31/01/2018`

By Simple Basic js we can do it:

```js
var time = "2018-01-31T11:11:41+05:30";
time =new Date(time);
console.log(time.toLocaleDateString())
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [momentjs timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/).

```js
var time = '2018-01-31T11:11:41+05:30';
console.log( moment(time).tz(moment.tz.guess()));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.14/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```